# air brake does not seem to log errors in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, airbrake

I have setup airbrake in my app but it doesn't seem to log any 500 errors I get in production. The error is most certain an action mailer issue but Airbrake is not catching this error.

I have no custom error handling in my app at this point removed it.
What would be a good way to determine why it doesn't log?

Comment: please add as much detail as you can. I can't help you otherwise. I'm almost sure it's a gem issue, so opening a new issue [here](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/issues/new) would be ideal. even better if you add cucumber scenarios, without the steps defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please make sure you're using the latest GEM http://rubygems.org/gems/airbrake .

Please send a support ticket to support@airbrake.io and we'll do our best to resolve this issue for you.

Comment: Thx Ben, it seems like the particular error is causing issues anyway ( action mailer connection issue ) with a custom error handler I didn't got any output in my production.log neither. I post a mail thx for the help!